# What is the relevant book for comparative mythology nowadays?

Tags: comparative, mythohistory

Since i am not in the field of mythology & folklore scholar but a reader.
I have interested some of topic in comparative mythology especially:

- The diffusions of mythology across the world.
- The influence from one myth that effect other race myth.
- The development of myth that came from other culture as well as
  adaptation of myth.
- Psychology in myth.

So i started with Greek myth of Edith Hamilton , some of Joseph Campbell's stuffs, James Frazer compacted golden bough, a little bit of Mircea Eliade, a little bit of Lévi-Strauss.

However, i alway told that some of those scholar's book/hypothesis was already outdated.

So what is the relevant book for this kind of subject or is there any relevant scholar on this field 'nowadays' ?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not really sure who the big contemporary names in comparative are.  One comment though, although the scientific method of Frazer is long outdated, the poetic truth of his hypothesis has been so profoundly influential in terms of 20th century literature, it's formed almost a new modern mythology. Influences include TS Eliot and Neil Gaiman.